# azure storage public website control access by azure domain controller

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage

I setup a static web site in azue storage, is it possible to control who have access to that website, I have read a couple of question here but I can't get my head around it.

let's say, I work in company new_KFC, all I want is only user1@new_KFC.com user2@new_KFC.com get access, all other user when they try to access the website, get error

we are already using azure active directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static websites are public access only. However, you can can build a separate authentication layer that protects your data through AAD Authentication using ADAL and Storage JS libraries. See a demo of a similar SPA from the last //build session: 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2018/BRK3313

Please also provide your feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/36453091-enable-authorization-to-the-azure-static-websites so that we understand your feedback/demand for this feature.

Thanks,

Aung Oo

Azure Storage PM Team